# Bash converting date in a csv file with awk or other linux tool (csvcut)

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, csv

```
awk -F"," '{OFS=","; $1=system("date -d "$1" +%d-%m-%Y") ; print $0}' data.csv | head
```

I am trying to take the first column of a csv file and standardize the date format to %dd-%mm-%yyyy.

When I try the code above I get date: write error: Broken pipe.

But when I try the code below:

```
dd=$(csvcut -c  1 -e ISO-8859-1 -d ","  data.csv | head -2 | sed -n 2p)
echo $dd
echo $(date -d $dd "+%d-%m-%Y")
```

I get the the output:

> 2017-02-03
>
> 03-02-2017

What am I doing wrong. Any hints? Thanks.

My system: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

EDIT 2: Here is a sample file: http://grn.dk/sites/default/files/attachments/data.csv

EDIT:

sure CSV data file (input): data.csv (with many rows)

```
Bogført,Tekst,Beløb,Saldo  

2017-02-03, random text,-425,-611524.54
```

output:

```
Bogført,Tekst,Beløb,Saldo    
03-02-2017, random text,-425,-611524.54
```

but the date format can be in any other format. I am currently looking into standardizing dates for an csv import job. Thanks.

Comment: can you give the sample input data and the expected output

Comment: sure CSV data file (input): data.csv (with many rows)  

    Bogført,Tekst,Beløb,Saldo  

    2017-02-03, random text,-425,-611524.54  

output:  

    Bogført,Tekst,Beløb,Saldo    
    03-02-2017, random text,-425,-611524.54  

but the date format can be in any other format. I am currently looking into standardizing dates for an csv import job. Thanks.

Comment: added with better formatting at the end of the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the `system()` function in the wrong way. Or rather, that's not what to use here as it doesn't return the output from the command, only the exit status (the output goes to the terminal).

Assuming `date` is GNU `date`, this is an `awk` script that will perform the date reformatting:

```
BEGIN { OFS = FS = "," }

$1 {
    cmd = sprintf("date -d '%s' '+%%d-%%m-%%Y' 2>/dev/null", $1);
    cmd | getline $1;
    print;
    close(cmd);
}
```

Running it:

```
$ awk -f script.awk data.csv
Bogført,Tekst,Beløb,Saldo
03-02-2017, random text,-425,-611524.54
```

The script will discard empty input lines. It creates a command string `cmd` that does the actual date conversion using GNU `date`. Errors from `date` will be thrown away (and `$1` will remain unchanged).

To do it with `cvssql` (from `csvkit`):

```
$ sed '1,2d' data.csv | csvsql -H --query 'SELECT strftime("%d-%m-%Y", a), b, c, d FROM stdin' | sed '1d' >new_data.csv
```

The data in `new_data.csv` will be without the header row. To add it back:

```
$ cat <( head -n 1 data.csv ) new_data.csv >even_newer_data.csv
```

Comment: Great thank you. I can make the awk script work, but I will need to be able to get the separator from my bash script, it is stored in a variable. Is there a hint to get it into the awk script or run the awk script from my main  bash script?  

The csvsql command gives me an error: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column: a [SQL: 'SELECT strftime("%d-%m-%Y", a), b, c, d FROM stdin']
  
I even tried to rename the columns in the data.csv file.  

Thanks.

Comment: @GrzegorzNowak Change the `BEGIN` block to `BEGIN { OFS = FS }` and run the script with `awk -F "$separator" -f script.awk data.csv`.

Comment: @GrzegorzNowak You get that error from `csvsql` if you forget the `-H` option.

Comment: Thanks it works like a charm! I did not forget the -H option, but nevermind the csvsql.

Answer (score 1):

```
bash-4.1$ cat a.txt
2017-02-03, random text,-425,-611524.54
2017-02-08, random text,-425,-611524.54
2017-02-07, random text,-425,-611524.54


bash-4.1$ awk -F, '{a="date -d "$1" +%Y%m%d"; while (a |getline line){$1=line;}print $0}' OFS=, a.txt
20170203, random text,-425,-611524.54
20170208, random text,-425,-611524.54
20170207, random text,-425,-611524.54

bash-4.1$ awk -F, '{a="date -d "$1" +%Y%m"; while (a |getline line){$1=line;}print $0}' OFS=, a.txt
201702, random text,-425,-611524.54
201702, random text,-425,-611524.54
201702, random text,-425,-611524.54

awk -F, 'NR==1{print;next}{a="date -d "$1" +%Y%m"; while (a |getline line){$1=line;}print $0}' OFS=, a.txt
```

Comment: This looks great, but somehow it does not work as intended. Because my output does not transform all the dates. Maybe something is wrong with my csv file?  

http://grn.dk/sites/default/files/attachments/data.csv  

My output is: 

`awk -F, '{a="date -d "$1" +%d-%m-%Y"; while (a |getline line){$1=line;}print $0}' OFS=, data.csv
date: invalid date ‘Bogført’
Bogført,Tekst,Beløb,Saldo  
03-02-2017,text1,-425,-611524.54
2017-02-03,"text2",-213.61,-611099.54
2017-02-03,text3,-116,-610885.93
02-02-2017,text4,-111.25,-610769.93`

Comment: added 1 more answer for ignoring the conversion for 1st line

Comment: Did you try my csv file? Thanks.

Comment: did you check my last answer ? NR==1

Comment: Thank you. Yes it skips the first line, but the real problem is that two of the dates in the csv-file are not converted.

`
awk -F, 'NR==1{print;next}{a="date -d "$1" +%d-%m-%Y"; while (a |getline line){$1=line;}print $0}' OFS=, data.csv
`

Comment: is the date and format is valid ? do you get any error ?

Comment: Yes, I think the date and format are valid. I don't get any errors. I just don't get the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Ubuntu, you probably have GNU `awk`, which provides useful time and date functions:

```
echo "2017-03-02" | \
awk '{ gsub(/-/, " ", $1); t = mktime($1 " 0 0 0"); print strftime("%d-%m-%Y", t);}'
```