# Running R project script with arguments within AWK in a Bash Script (Ubuntu Linux)

Tags: bash, awk, r

I have this code where the cmd usually works if I sprintf something to it, but when I try to run my Rscript, it does not work. Any hints?

I get the error:

```
awk: cmd. line:9:         cmd = Rscript ./date-script-r.r $1 3 2 1;
awk: cmd. line:9:                       ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:9:         cmd = Rscript ./date-script-r.r $1 3 2 1;
awk: cmd. line:9:                         ^ unterminated regexp
```

Code:

```
awk=/usr/bin/awk

awkcommand='
#d is the delimiter
BEGIN { OFS = FS = d }

$1 {
    #Expected args for the Rscript: (1, 2, 3, 4) = (dateString, yearPosition, monthPosition, dayPosition)
    cmd = Rscript ./date-script-r.r $1 3 2 1;
    cmd | getline $1;
    print;
    close(cmd);
}

awk -v d="," "$awkcommand" output-data/$filename > output-data/tmp.csv
```

Example of R-script output:

```
Rscript date-script-r.r 17-12-12 1 2 3
12-12-2017
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace

```
cmd = Rscript ./date-script-r.r $1 3 2 1;
```

by

```
cmd = "Rscript ./date-script-r.r " $1 " 3 2 1" ;
```

for complex awk script it might be better to put them in a awk-script, e.g. `date-awk.awk`

```
$1 {
    #Expected args for the Rscript: (1, 2, 3, 4) = (dateString, yearPosition, monthPosition, dayPosition)
    cmd = "Rscript ./date-script-r.r " "$1" " 3 2 1";
    cmd | getline $1;
    print;
    close(cmd);
}
```

that you would call with

```
awk  -F, -f date-awk.awk  output-data/$filename > output-data/tmp.csv
```

note that

- `-F,` will set , as separator, there is no need for a relay variable.
- I expect this is part of a bigger scheme, or self tutorial. (there are easier way to compute date in shell or in awk).

Comment: Great thanks it works! I got help with the first part of the script using the date function (http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/344794/bash-converting-date-in-a-csv-file-with-awk-or-other-linux-tool-csvcut), but it does not meet the requirements for complex date auto detection. So yes, it is part of a larger and more complex script. Thanks for the help regarding running the Rscript. :-)
I actually need to estimate where the days, months, and years, are when I have different input files with dates like 17-02-02  and 02-02-02. The gnu date function "fails" here.