# Why does this gawk coprocess hang?

Tags: gawk, concurrency, coprocesses

While having a go at [Convert date in bash shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/368234/70524), I tried [GNU awk's coprocess feature](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline_002fCoprocess.html#Getline_002fCoprocess):

```
gawk -F, -v cmd='date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" -f-' '{print $5 |& cmd; cmd |& getline d; $5 = d}1' foo
```

This command hangs. I thought this might be because `date` is waiting to read the entire input, so I tried to close the sending half of the pipeline:

```
gawk -F, -v cmd='date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" -f-' '{print $5 |& cmd; close(cmd, "to"); cmd |& getline d; $5 = d}1' foo
```

This works (yes, I know I should set `OFS=,`, but for now...).

However, `date` seems to have no problem processing input as it comes in. This gives the first line of output immediately:

```
d='Thu Apr 27 2017 23:19:47 GMT+0700 (ICT)'
(echo "$d"; sleep 1m; echo "$d") |
  date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" -f-
```

What's going on?

Comment: You're writing, then reading from the same process.  This is a well-known deadlock case, nothing to do with `date` or `gawk` in particular.  It's pretty hard to solve, too.

Comment: @SatoKatsura sure, but `date`, unlike say, `sort`, shouldn't have to process input line-by-line... If this is really that common, the coprocess feature would be worthless.

Comment: Processing input line by line helps if you have unbuffered (or at least line-buffered) I/O.  Perl has [`IPC::Open2`](http://perldoc.perl.org/IPC/Open2.html) to work around this problem.  No idea what `gawk` does about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like many other programs, `date`'s output is buffered when stdout is not a tty. Invoking it through `stdbuf -oL` you'll have it flush output at each line, and your first Gawk sample code will just work (no need to close the pipe's write end).

Comment: Yep, that seems to be it.