# How to convert Syslog Date-Time [UTC] to Epoch?

Tags: linux, awk, grep, syslog, gawk

I am currently piecing together a tool to work with Syslogs generated in my network, one of the requirements is to convert the DateTime from the format in which it is in syslog (%b %d %Y %T) to epoch. In essence, this is what I am trying to achieve:

Original Syslog format:

```
1:      Jul 02 2019 15:14:19: %ASA-6-106015: <message> 
2:      Jul 02 2019 15:14:49: %ASA-6-106015: <message>
```

Final Log:

```
1:      1562080489   %ASA-6-106015  <message>
2:      1562080529   %ASA-6-106015  <message>
```

I know that I can do this by iterating through the entire log and performing a date -d operation. This is something I want to avoid. I prefer using GAWK time functions.

Here is my approach,

```
gawk -F: '{ print strftime("%s", timestamp}' syslog.log
```

But here the timestamp must be in the same format as the value returned by the systime() function. Which it isn't.

Also, I cannot use the mktime() function to convert syslog timestamp to the required format since it accepts input only if it is in a specific format [YYYY MM DD HH MM SS]

I feel there is a method to do this, but I am missing it. Any alternate methods will also be appreciated.

Comment: what local time is the log file using? I've tried converting it with `TZ=UTC`, but the result is 30 minutes off.

Comment: @mosvy Its actually GMT+5:30

Comment: s/minutes/seconds/ in my comment above. Converting with GMT+5:30 will **not** result in those values. And I'm pretty sure that *not* passing each line back and forth between two processes is faster than doing it ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU `date`, you can run `date` once and have it take input from stdin. Using [gawk's coprocess feature](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline_002fCoprocess.html#Getline_002fCoprocess) to have a single instance each of `awk` and `date` process all the dates:

```
% awk -v cmd='stdbuf -oL date +%s -f-' -F': ' 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} {print $2 |& cmd; cmd |& getline $2} 1' foo
1: 1562048059: %ASA-6-106015: <message>
2: 1562048089: %ASA-6-106015: <message>
```

Note that [`date`'s output needs to be unbuffered](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/525862/70524) (hence the `stdbuf -oL`), otherwise the coprocess will hang.

Comment: Why `coprocess`? What's wrong with: `awk -F': ' 'BEGIN{cmd="date +%s -d "; OFS=FS} {exe=cmd "\"" $2 "\"";exe |& getline $2}1' file`

Comment: Why execute `date` so many times, when just once will do? That's why OP is avoiding it - they're going to run it on large log files (see other questions by them)

Comment: Got it, thanks. @muru.

Answer (score 1):

Just like the `date(1)` utility, `gawk`'s `mktime()` assumes that the date spec is using the local time.

To force it to use `UTC`, the `TZ` envvar should be used:

```
$ TZ=UTC gawk -F'[: ]+' '{sub(/([^:]+:){4} */, mktime(sprintf("%s %02d %s %d %d %d", $3, index("  JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",$1)/3, $2, $4, $5, $6))"\t"$7"\t"); print}'
1562080459      %ASA-6-106015   <message>
1562080489      %ASA-6-106015   <message>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a typical way of converting the month names into numbers by using an associative array where the index is the month name and the value is the month number. Eg `mon["Jul"]` is 7. This is setup once in the BEGIN block.

```
awk 'BEGIN { 
       split("Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec",months," ")
       for(i=1;i<=12;i++)mon[months[i]] = i }
     { m = $2; d = $3; y = $4; t = $5; gsub(":"," ",t)
       print mktime(y " " mon[m] " " d " " t) }'
```

Then for each line the various fields are re-arranged into the right order for `mktime()` and concatenated with intervening spaces. The time `t` field has the `:` converted to space.  The above just prints the epoch time, you still need to add the rest of the data.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps perl:

```
perl -MTime::Piece -i.bak -pe '
    if ( /([[:upper:]][[:lower:]]{2} \d{2} \d{4} \d\d:\d\d:\d\d)/ ) {
        $datetime = Time::Piece->strptime($1, "%b %d %Y %T");
        $epoch = $datetime->epoch;
        s/$timestamp/$epoch/
    }
' log_file
```