# Convert Date time on fly in BASH

Tags: text-processing, date, conversion

I have a file with following enteries

```
Nov 29 15:15 ,alert_logevent
Nov 29 15:15 ,alert_webhook
Nov 29 15:15 ,appsbrowser
Oct 20 2017 ,ClearPassOnSplunk_2
Oct 10 2017 ,Dnslookup
Oct 12 2017 ,domainCategories
```

I want to convert date time to YYYYMMDDHHMMSS with out using loops
some thing like this

```
 cat SOMEFILE_WITH_DATE_AND_DATE | awk '{print "date -d \""$1, $2, $3"\"" " +" "%Y%m%d%H%M%S" , $4 }'
```

I want the output to look like this

```
20181129151500,alert_logevent
20181129151500,alert_webhook
20181129151500,appsbrowser
20181129151500,appsbrowser
```

and so forth

I tried system () function in awk but it does not accept more than 1 argument.

Comment: How are you coming up with HH MM and SS for “Oct 12 2018”?

Comment: Don't `cat file | awk 'stuff'`; that's a Useless Use of `cat`.  Instead, `awk 'stuff' file`.

Comment: About `system()` in `awk`, https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/344855/14831 might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how your expected output relates to your input. I would suggest:

```
$ perl -MPOSIX -MDate::Parse -pe 's{[^,]*}{
   strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S", localtime str2time($&))}e' <your-file
20171129151500,alert_logevent
20171129151500,alert_webhook
20171129151500,appsbrowser
20171020000000,ClearPassOnSplunk_2
20171010000000,Dnslookup
20171012000000,domainCategories
```

To use GNU `date`'s ability to parse those dates, and avoid running one `date` invocation per line, you could do (assuming a  shell with support for ksh-style process-substitution (like ksh, bash or zsh)):

```
paste -d , <(<yourfile cut -d , -f1 | date -f- +%Y%m%d%H%M%S) \
           <(<yourfile cut -d , -f2-)
```

Note however that it gives:

```
20181129151500,alert_logevent
20181129151500,alert_webhook
20181129151500,appsbrowser
20171020000000,ClearPassOnSplunk_2
20171010000000,Dnslookup
20171012000000,domainCategories
```

Though it's what you asked, it sounds unlikely that it is what you want as those `Nov 29 15:15` sound more likely to be timestamps from 2017 (last year) than some in the future.

Here, it looks like those dates are as reported by `ls -l` in the POSIX locale. So portably, you could adapt [that function from another Q&A](/a/255529) to convert it to a more useful format. Or better, use a better way than `ls -l` to store file dates in the file in the first place (like GNU `find -printf` or GNU `date -r` or zsh `stat`, or GNU/BSD `stat` or ast `ls --format`...) where you can use a more useful, precise and unambiguous format.

Answer (score 0):

If zero `000000` is ok as `HHMMSS` for entries without *time* data, use the following **`awk`** approach:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS = OFS = "," }
     { 
         cmd = "date -d\042" $1 "\042 +%Y%m%d%H%M%S";
         cmd | getline d; close(cmd);
         print d, $2
     }' file
```

The output:

```
20181129151500,alert_logevent
20181129151500,alert_webhook
20181129151500,appsbrowser
20171020000000,ClearPassOnSplunk_2
20171010000000,Dnslookup
20171012000000,domainCategories
```

Answer (score 0):

Requires GNU awk for the builtin time functions

```
gawk -F, -v OFS=, '
    BEGIN {
        # assumes english month names
        split("Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec", m, ",")
        for (idx in m) months[m[idx]] = idx
        delete m
    }
    function date2timestamp(datestamp,    tmp,now,timestamp,year,hour,minute) {
        now = systime()
        split(datestamp, tmp, " ")
        if (tmp[3] ~ /:/) {
            year = strftime("%Y", now)
            hour = substr(tmp[3], 1, 2)
            minute = substr(tmp[3], 4, 2)
        }
        else {
            year = tmp[3]
            hour = minute = 0
        }
        timestamp = mktime(year " " months[tmp[1]] " " tmp[2] " " hour " " minute " 0")
        if (timestamp > now)
            timestamp = mktime((year-1) " " months[tmp[1]] " " tmp[2] " " hour " " minute " 0")
        return strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M00", timestamp)
    }
    {
        $1 = date2timestamp($1)
        print
    }
' file
```

output

```
20171129151500,alert_logevent
20171129151500,alert_webhook
20171129151500,appsbrowser
20171020000000,ClearPassOnSplunk_2
20171010000000,Dnslookup
20171012000000,domainCategories
```

---

Your input file looks like the result of [parsing `ls -l`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Formatting-file-timestamps.html#Formatting-file-timestamps). You might want to skip that file and do something like

```
stat -c '%Y,%n' * | gawk -F, -v OFS=, '{$1 = strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S", $1)}1'
```

This isn't safe (in the sense of handling filenames with newlines) but it will give you the accurate file mtime.